# AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found. getting 403 forbidden

Tags: php, docker

Pls who can help me out with this error from docker. I'm new to docker but following all the steps in the tutorial, I keep getting this error.

this is the error.

`AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

this is my Docker file

`FROM php:8.0-apache COPY todo/ var/www/html/ EXPOSE 80`

Can someone help me? (Please ask for more information, if they needed)

i was expecting it to load the index file of the project when I check http://localhost:80 but I keep getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: _"i was expecting it to load the index file"_ - _what_ index file? According to the error message, neither a `index.php` or `index.html` exist ... so what is your index file named then?

Comment: # cd var
# ls
www
# cd www 
# ls
html
# cd html
# ls 
 Dockerfile   app.js   fontawesome   index.php   reference.png   style.css  'todo list.png'  'todo list.zip'   user4.png                  these are the list of files and folder in the html

Comment: Please see [ask] and [MCVE]. You execute `COPY todo/ var/www/html/` and that copies `todo` to `/root/var/www/html/`. Try simply changing second argument of `COPY` to `/var/www/html/`.